# Can I only checkout the head revision in subversion to keep the working copy as small as possible?

Tags: svn, version-control

I'm (ab)using subversion to deploy software to clients. It's ideal for us, since we can easily update, delete or create files on the clients and are also able to rollback changes on the repository if necessary. 
A downside however is that the clients download all revision into their working copy if they do a checkout, which makes it quite large after some time. They don't need those however, since they aren't "working" on it and are not supposed to rollback changes locally.

Now I found out that it's possible to checkout certain revision, f.e. the head revision with the following command:

```
svn checkout svn://example.net/svn/example@head ./
```

If I do that, will each checkout "overwrite" the head revision of the working copy, making it only contain the latest revision, or will the old head revisions be kept?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "... the clients download all revision into their working copy if they do a checkout ...". When you do a code-checkout you will not get all historical elements - only code form revesion you checked out.

Comment: At the moment, I perform a checkout without a specific revision: `svn checkout svn://example.net/svn/example ./` . Doesn't this download ALL revisions ? F.e. if the head revision is revision 5, won't this also download 4,3,2 and 1?

Comment: No, you get everything revision 5 defined. For example if you delete a file in rev 4 then rev 5 will not download this file.

Comment: Let's say a 20Mb file is committed in revision 1. Revision 2 edits it so its only 19MB, then revision 3 edits it so its only 18MB, rev 4 makes it 17MB, rev 5 makes it 16MB. Now a user who hasn't done any checkout before "checks out" the repository. How much MB would he download? As far as I understand, he would download 90 MB ( all revisions, since the file has changed ).

Comment: For most checkouts I'm using TortoiseSVN. So I have to specify a revesion or Tortoise use HEAD. So in your example it will download 16MB. If it would download everything after time you would get a "nonsense" codebase and in terms of deleting/adding files it won't be possible. What should happened for example if you add in rev 1 a file called 1.txt delete it in rev 2 and add file 1.txt in rev 3 again, but with other content - what should he download? how would naming of the file be?

Comment: Please see my answer. I suppose you confusing svn-checkout and svn-update.

Comment: In your example I would want it to download 1.txt from revision 3. But to come back to my question: So you are saying subversion doesn't download prior revisions and is only keeping 1 revision a time in working copies? So the old revision wont be kept in its internal database in the .svn folder?

Comment: yes, therefor the name "working copie". Previous revision will stay in svn-repository not in .svn folder (simplified).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I do that, will each checkout "overwrite" the head revision of the
>   working copy, making it only contain the latest revision, or will the
>   old head revisions be kept?

You do a **checkout** for a special branch (or trunk or what else) **only once**. After that you have to use svn **update**-function. Otherwise it will copy all revisions in one folder which will lead you to some very "special moments" over time ;-)

Previous revision will stay in svn-repository not in lokal .svn folder (simplified). Working copy will have a relation to **one** revision in repository (with lokal changes which are not comited).

Comment: You are right. I got completely mixed up there. Shame on me. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: "Shame on me" - SVN is sometimes confusing - so no reason to be shamed :-). Thanks for accepting (+1 for that).